# Load category with products from database

Tags: php, mysql

I try to get the product category and the products out of the database.
My database looks like this:

```
categories
+---+--------+
|id |category|
| 1 |  Toys  |
| 2 |  Books |
| 3 |  Music |
+---+--------+

products
+---+--------+
|id |products|
|1  | Puzzle |
|2  |  Lego  |
|3  |  Duplo |
|4  |  Sia   |
+---+--------+

relation
+-----+-----+
|proid|catid|
|  1  |  1  |
|  2  |  1  |
|  3  |  1  |
|  4  |  3  |
+-----+-----+
```

Below my PHP code

```
<?php            
$sql    = " SELECT relation.catid, products.product, categories.category
            FROM relation 
            JOIN categories ON relation.catid = categories.id
            JOIN products ON relation.proid = products.id";

$result            = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);             
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){    
?>
<h1><?php echo $row['category']; ?></h1>
<span><?php echo $row['product']; ?></span>
<?php
}
?>
```

The code above works but I have an issue.
The category name is displayed every time.

```
<h1>Toys</h1>
<span>Puzzle</span>
<h1>Toys</h1>
<span>Lego</span>
<h1>Toys</h1>
<span>Duplo</span>
<h1>Music</h1>
<span>Sia</span>
```

Below my expected result

```
<h1>Toys</h1>
<span>Puzzle</span>
<span>Lego</span>
<span>Duplo</span>
<h1>Music</h1>
<span>Sia</span>
```

Hope somebody can help me.

Comment: What's the expected result?

Comment: Hi The Impaler I add my expected result in my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an option:

```
$sql = "SELECT relation.catid, products.product, categories.category
        FROM relation
        JOIN categories ON relation.catid = categories.id
        JOIN products ON relation.proid = products.id";

$output = [];
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $output[$row['category']][] = $row['product'];
}

foreach ($output as $category => $products) {
    echo "<h1>$category</h1>";
    foreach ($products as $product) {
        echo "<span>$product</span>";
    }
}
```

Comment: The good answer should say also why this approach would work and where the OP mistaken.

Answer (score 0):

If your categories are sorted then you can collect these values in array and use each new value once:

```
...
$un_vals = [];
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){    
?>
   <?php if (!in_array($row['category'],$un_vals) {?> 
       <h1><?php echo $row['category']; $un_vals[] = $row['category']; ?></h1>
   <?php } ?>
       <span><?php echo $row['product']; ?></span>

<?php
...
```